# Android and JSP: xml in http post request

Tags: android, xml, jsp, http-post

I should send within an http post request (inside the request body) an xml string formatted like the following:

```
<message>
<man>
<age>18</age>
<sex>m</sex>
</man>
<result>
<math>8</math>
<science>8</science>
</result>
</message>
```

The POST requests should have a Content-Type header set to "text/xml; charset=UTF-8".
How can i do this? i din't get how httppost works for jsp...heeelp! :)

Comment: Where is the link from Android to JSP?

Comment: i have to send the http post request from android devices and receive it in a jsp local service.

Comment: Got the answer here:

http://amitkgaur.blogspot.com/2009/12/post-xml-data-without-form-in-jsp-and.html

thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this should be this:

http://amitkgaur.blogspot.it/2009/12/post-xml-data-without-form-in-jsp-and.html